# How to identify the tty file for one specific Arduino when several are connected through Serial/USB link?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, ftdi

I have a PC with three Arduinos (Nano Every) connected to it. Each Arduino runs the same program and acts as a simple interface between the PC and another device.

```
  ┌────────────────────────────────────┐
  │                P C                 │
  └───┬─────────────┬─────────────┬────┘
┌─────┴─────┐ ┌─────┴─────┐ ┌─────┴─────┐
│ Arduino#1 │ │ Arduino#2 │ │ Arduino#3 │
└─────┬─────┘ └─────┬─────┘ └─────┬─────┘
┌─────┴─────┐ ┌─────┴─────┐ ┌─────┴─────┐
│ Device #1 │ │ Device #2 │ │ Device #3 │
└───────────┘ └───────────┘ └───────────┘
```

I developed a C program that opens 3 `ttyUSBx` and dialogs with the 3 Arduinos in order to control the Devices. However, I have to manually specify, when launching the program, which `ttyUSBx` must be used to connect with each Arduino.

The program is intended to be used by people that will work with a dozen of Arduinos and will plug/unplug them quite often (never having more than 3 at a time plugged into the machine). As a result, having to manually find the correct `ttyUSBx` for each Arduino at runtime is not acceptable.

A possible solution to this issue would be to add udev rules. But unfortunately, this is not possible due to some restrictive admin guidelines on the machine.

Is there a way to programmatically link a given Arduino to its `ttyUSBx`?

Comment: you can't solve it at the USB level. let the Arduino send some id on request from the C program

Comment: Design your communication protocol in such a way where each of Arduino send a unique ID (MAC address for example) together with data, and use the unique ID to identify which Arduino the data from.

Comment: Assuming these Arduinos have different serial numbers (how to use the udev rules otherwise?) one can parse `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id` output to get the serno -> ttyUSBx map.